# gdb not setting breakpoint on correct line

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm working through a bug in Qt/zlib at the moment, and I'm trying to check whether a variable has become corrupt prior to the line it's crashing on, so I've used `break 1245` to set the break on the previous line, however:

```
(gdb) info break
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
6       breakpoint     keep y   0x02cb0e1e in inflateEnd at inflate.c:1245
breakpoint already hit 6 times
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Thread 0xb103db70 (LWP 26146) exited]
[Thread 0xb5a74b70 (LWP 26143) exited]

Breakpoint 6, inflateEnd (strm=0x86ccdc0) at inflate.c:1246
1246        if (state->window != Z_NULL) ZFREE(strm, state->window);
```

Which is the line that it's SEGFAULTing on rather than the breakpoint I've set. Bug in gdb or some quirky behaviour?

EDIT: Adding the list of the area I'm working on:

```
(gdb) list
1241    {
1242        struct inflate_state FAR *state;
1243        if (strm == Z_NULL || strm->state == Z_NULL || strm->zfree ==         (free_func)0)
1244            return Z_STREAM_ERROR;
1245        state = (struct inflate_state FAR *)strm->state;
1246        if (state->window != Z_NULL) ZFREE(strm, state->window);
1247        ZFREE(strm, strm->state);
1248        strm->state = Z_NULL;
1249        Tracev((stderr, "inflate: end\n"));
1250        return Z_OK;
(gdb)
```

EDIT: Took the advice from the comments and rebuilt it using the source packages from ubuntu (apt-get source) and building with CFLAGS and SFLAGS forced to -O0, however it now doesn't return any line numbers within gdb for the segfault, so I think I've gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Using system installed zlib with -dbg package from apt, so I wouldn't be able to answer fully.

Comment: Updated with the code block I'm looking at.

Comment: As far as I know no, so the zlib timeline was this. 1) Ubuntu installed, zlib package included, 2) zlib-dbg & -dev packages installed, 3) same day when working on the crash apt-get source zlib used to get the source for the same package currently installed. Loaded with directory zlib-1.2.3.4.dfsg.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question of Paul R. If you want to debug, you need to have an unoptimized binary to be able to understand whats going on under the hood.

Comment: Certainly doesn't, but mucking around with zlib possibly falls under the category of 'there'll be dragons'. I'll build a separate copy later on and see if it improves it, but I'd guess that the development/debug libraries within the apt system would be built non-optimised, not very useful otherwise for debug purposes.

Comment: As said before, you will need to use the library unoptimized build to set a break point at this precise location. Instead, set your break point at the beginning of the function (and hope it is not inlined)

Comment: Function (thankfully) isn't inlined, but having it at the start is slightly less useful, but I'm going to build a non-optimised version now and we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which is the line that it's SEGFAULTing on rather than the breakpoint I've set

This is expected when debugging optimized code (which `inflate.c` likely is). The compiler moves instructions around, making code execution "jump around" when you step through it.